# Help needed on remainder theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

A function $f(x)$ is divisible by $x+2$ and leaves a remainder of $12$ when divided by $x$. Find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divded by $x^2+2x$.

**My attempt**

$$f(x)=D(x)Q(x)+R(x)$$

Therefore

$$f(x)=xQ_1(x)+12=0$$
$$f(x)=(x+2)Q_2(x)=0$$
$$f(x)=(x^2+2x)Q_3(x)+R(x)$$

From the second equation,

$$x+2=0$$
$$x=-2$$

But I am lost what to do next. Any hints? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you mean $f(x) = x Q_1(x) + 12$, not $f(x) = x Q_1(x) = 12$. Probably the question should say "polynomial" rather than "function". General functions don't have remainders when divided.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you for pointing out the typo. The question indeed said "function". Anyhow, how should I proceed with this?

Comment: Your $=0$ pieces don't make sense. We don't assume that $f(x)=0$ for any value of $x$ at all. (Though we can show $f(-2)=0$.) My next step would be $x Q_1(x) + 12 = (x+2) Q_2(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I would write $f(x)=(x^2+2x)\cdot Q(x)+(ax+b)$ with $ax+b$ being the form of the remainder for a degree two divisor. You mention the Remainder Theorem in the title of your post, so I assume you are familiar with it.

Using the Remainder Theorem, $f(0)=12$ and $f(-2)=0$. Plugging this information into the first equation, you should be able to find $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 0):

The remainder on division by a quadratic is at most a linear function, so $$f(x)=x(x+2)Q(x)+ax+b$$

You have $$f(-2)=0\implies 0=-2a+b$$
And also, $$f(0)=12\implies 12=b$$
So $$a=6$$

So the required remainder is $$6x+12$$